# Sharepoint: How to hide a SharePoint list from some users?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, rest, sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint hosted list which I want to hide from some user by using code. Not hide from browser. Cause I want the admin can access to it and change something when they need. And the entire list should be hidden from user, not only some fields or column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide it from ALL users you may use [hidden property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.hidden.aspx) of List Class.
If you want to hide this link for a set of users you have two options:

1. Play with [permissions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Edit-permissions-for-a-list-library-or-individual-item-02D770F3-59EB-4910-A608-5F84CC297782) of the list.
2. You also can play with [Audiences](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Target-content-to-specific-audiences-33D84CB6-14ED-4E53-A426-74C38EA32293).

Answer (score 0):

Break the permissions in list settings
remove the users/groups which you don't want to show the list.
give permissions only to those users/groups which you want to show the list.

Comment: Is "Break Permission" a safe way? I mean is it possible for user to access the list by the address ? Is there any other way such as using JavaScript ?

Comment: Yes its a safe way, after breaking the permission user can not access the list if they are not in the permission.